# Open winvideo stream with push of a button in Matlab

Tags: matlab, button, video-capture, matlab-figure

I am trying to figure out how to run the camera and stop the camera at the push of a button. If I cant do that, how do I set up camera to run within this figure and I will have it run all the time. Also I need to capture an image.

```
function faceCam2()
vid = videoinput('winvideo');

% Create a figure window
hFig = figure('Toolbar','none',...
       'Menubar', 'none',...
       'NumberTitle','Off',...
       'Name','FaceScan');

%start camera
uicontrol(  'String', 'Start Preview',...
            'Callback', 'preview(vid)',...
            'Units','normalized',...
            'Position',[0 0 0.15 .07]);     
%stop
uicontrol(  'String', 'Stop Preview',...
            'Callback', 'stoppreview(vid)',...
            'Units','normalized',...
            'Position',[.17 0 .15 .07]);
%snapshot
uicontrol(  'String', 'Pic',...
            'Callback', 'data = getsnapshot(vid)',...
            'Units','normalized',...
            'Position',[0.34 0 .15 .07]);
%close window
uicontrol(  'String', 'Close',...
            'Callback', 'close(gcf)',...
            'Units','normalized',...
            'Position',[0.51 0 .15 .07]);

end
```

I get the Error in matlab command window when I press a button. Quit works, but not the other 3. What do I need to do?
Thanks!

Undefined function or variable 'vid'.

Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `vid` is a local variable in the function `faceCam2` and is not visible to the callback. [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/sharing-data-among-a-guis-callbacks.html) are a few methods to pass data to callback functions. When using nested methods, the code looks like this:

```
function faceCam2()
vid = videoinput('winvideo');

% Create a figure window
hFig = figure('Toolbar','none',...
       'Menubar', 'none',...
       'NumberTitle','Off',...
       'Name','FaceScan');

%start camera
uicontrol(  'String', 'Start Preview',...
            'Callback', @prevCallback,...
            'Units','normalized',...
            'Position',[0 0 0.15 .07]);     

    function prevCallback(hObject,eventdata)
       preview(vid);
    end
%...
end
```

Comment: I did so, but the camera doesnt start up when I press the button now. I just did 
function prevCallback()
       preview(vid);
    end